# In beautifulsoup, how to collect a photo link that does not appear in the parser?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, src

In python 3 I want to get the links from photos that are on certain pages, such as:

http://divulgacandcontas.tse.jus.br/divulga/#/candidato/2018/2022802018/AC/10000600209

http://divulgacandcontas.tse.jus.br/divulga/#/candidato/2018/2022802018/SP/250000627809

I did so:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error

html = urlopen('http://divulgacandcontas.tse.jus.br/divulga/#/candidato/2018/2022802018/AC/10000600209')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
link = soup.find("img", {"class": "img-thumbnail img-responsive dvg-cand-foto"})
print(link)
None

html = urlopen('http://divulgacandcontas.tse.jus.br/divulga/#/candidato/2018/2022802018/SP/250000627809')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
link = soup.find("img", {"class": "img-thumbnail img-responsive dvg-cand-foto"})
print(link)
None
```

I intended to collect the set of items next to the photo and define another strategy to get the exact point of the src. As: http://divulgacandcontas.tse.jus.br/candidaturas/oficial/2018/BR/AC/2022802018/10000600209/foto_1532971768767.jpg

But what appears in the Inspect Element of the Firefox browser (img class='img-thumbnail img-responsive dvg-cand-foto') was not the same as the html.parser it collected

Please, does anyone know how I can collect this photo link on the site?

-/-

With the use of selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
browser = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
browser.implicitly_wait(10)

browser.get('http://divulgacandcontas.tse.jus.br/divulga/#/candidato/2018/2022802018/SP/250000627809')

html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
browser.close()

link = soup.find("img", {"class": "img-thumbnail img-responsive dvg-cand-foto"})['src']

print(link)
http://divulgacandcontas.tse.jus.br/candidaturas/oficial/2018/BR/SP/2022802018/250000627809/foto_1534447872273.jpg
```

Comment: Thank you. I put up a possibility

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
browser = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
browser.implicitly_wait(10)

browser.get('http://divulgacandcontas.tse.jus.br/divulga/#/candidato/2018/2022802018/SP/250000627809')

html = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
browser.close()

link = soup.find("img", {"class": "img-thumbnail img-responsive dvg-cand-foto"})['src']

print(link)
http://divulgacandcontas.tse.jus.br/candidaturas/oficial/2018/BR/SP/2022802018/250000627809/foto_1534447872273.jpg
```